# Access and modify files on the SD card of my mobile using WIFI tethering

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wifi-hotspot

I am looking for an application for my Android 2.3.5 Sony Xperia X10i.

I want an app that will mount my phone on my hot spot as eg: `http://192.36.02.08` , which will have both download and upload functions.

I want this so that I can quickly transfer files from my computer to my mobile in a hurry, as I have found out that WiFi speeds for file transfers are much faster than that of an USB cable.

Are there any apps that can do it?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got quite a few Apps that can do it:

[Wifi File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorer)

[Wifi File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer)

3rd: WifiDroid, it doesn't let me post more than two links because of my reputation, but you can search in google.

4th: AirDroid, it allows you to transfer anything, and even control your phone with it.

I've used the first too, both free and pro versions, i like the 2nd more, the 3rd i never used.

Comment: The second one only worked, but it can only transfer upto 5MB per file. Is there anything else?

Comment: Niether the first nor 3rd worked? That's odd, check [WifiShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iiitd.muc.wifishare) You can also try [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include AirDroid. I transferred a big file to my phone today and it went blazing fast. Only problem is with the security.

Comment: With security? I haven't used it in awhile but i believe it does allow password to authenticate and https, or am i wrong?
Anyway i edited the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The pro version of WiFi File Transfer allows files of up to unlimited sizes to be transferred. You type the IP of the phone in the URL bar, and it takes you to the root directory of the phone, where you can go to the SD Card, or Internal Storage.[image: Screenshot of WiFi File Transfer Pro]

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransferpro

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

1. **FTP**: Access your phone via FTP. An Allrounder would be *[ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)*. Use an FTP client on your computer or i.e. the Firefox add-on *[FireFTP](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/fireftp/)*.

   - Access the mobile Hotspot
   - Open *ES File Explorer > Tools > Remote Manager > Start...*
   - Enter ftp-address in *FireFTP* to access files from the mobile (no system files!)
2. **Samba**: Use the Samba protocol if you **rooted** your device. *[Samba Filesharing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba)* is a good app. You can than connect your phones storage as a network drive on the computer.
3. **SSH**: It is possible to mount the phones storage on the computer using SSHFS. On a **rooted** Android device, use *[SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid)* and on the computer you have to find solutions to support SSHFS, ie. for Windows it is [win-sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/).
   It dempends highly on your setup. The difficulty varies between the various OS'es.

Comment: I might have misinterpreted your question. How exactly is your setup?